# laravel 5 method does not exist - why can't i access my function?

Tags: php, methods, laravel-5

I am having trouble calling a method in my Account class.

Here is the method defined in my class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['customer_id','bookmaker_id', 'balance', 'profit'];

    public function addProfit($amountToAdd) {
        $this->profit = $this->profit + $amountToAdd;
    }

.......
......
```

Here is my method call in my controller

```
$account->addProfit(5);
```

I have established that I am returning a single account record with the     `dd($account)` command, so it appears it's definitely a problem with the method.

However, I get this message when I try to run the code:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method addProfit does not exist.
```

Comment: Why don't add  the addProfit method directly to the controller?

Comment: thanks. my problem was actually with my getting $account. I use get() instead of first() so it acted all strange - info came from here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/method-save-does-not-exist?page=1

Comment: does that mean the problem has been solved?

Comment: yes - i did resolve this. a long time ago of course :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters the same issue, Laravel will only call the Model's method if called on **one single** object. If you have created a custom function in your Model.php file called `getAge` on a `User` model, for instance, you have to make sure that in the expression `$object->getAge()`, $object is **one** object. This is where using `->first()` instead of just `->get()` becomes relevant